# How keep these 2 logics in one IF statement formula?

Tags: formula-field

Net Amount part works as expected but CPq level max does not work.How I can add or/ add functions to this formula?

```java
IF( 
    SBQQ__NetAmount__c <= 7500, 
    " Approval Required ",
    IF(
        SBQQ__NetAmount__c > 7500, 
        " Approval Not Required ",
        IF(
            CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c = 1, 
            IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hl9z&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276904000', 'Green') ,
            IF(
                CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c = 2, 
                IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0158K0000000Xrs&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276872000', 'Blue'),
                IF(
                    CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c = 3,
                    IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hl9y&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276772000', 'Yellow'),
                    IF(
                        CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c = 4,
                        IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hlA0&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276863000', 
'Red'),
                        IF(
                            CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c = 5, 
                            IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hl9x&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652290642000', 'Black'), 
                            "N/A"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Formatting your formula as code will generally help make it easier to read (otherwise StackExchange will ignore newlines and just try to show it as one big run-on sentence). StackExchange sites (like this one) use a format called _Markdown_ to dictate how to display text (things like code blocks, bulleted lists, bold and italic, etc...). I've done this formatting for you again. You can click the `edited x time ago` link to see exactly what changes I made (if you select "Side-by-side Markdown").

Comment: Thank you Derek. However, this formula works for NetAmount and i am not sure how make these 2fields trigger correctly. Or lets say NetAmoun >7500 and CPQ level ma 1

Comment: Hi Ulvia, do you want the image to show or do you want the text "Approval (Not) Required"? Unfortunately, you can't have both. Could you update your question explaining what you want the formula to display?

Comment: Fred, thank you for your comment. I was thinking the same that I cannot keep these 2 logics in one formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling back to your previous question, the opposite of `SBQQ__NetAmount__c <= 7500` is `SBQQ__NetAmount__c > 7500`. Those two conditions cover every possible number.

So while your formula is syntactically correct, it is impossible to ever get into the part of the formula where you start checking `CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c`.

I assume that the behavior you want is something like:

- If no approval is required, return "No Approval Required"
- If approval is required and not yet given (i.e. `CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c` is blank), then return "Approval Required"
- If approval is required and has been given, display a color corresponding to the approval level

The important part that your formula is missing is the "approval is required **and not yet given**" part. You can't simply leave it at "approval is required".

So I'd restructure your formula as follows

```java
IF(
    SBQQ__NetAmount__c > 7500, 
    "Approval Not Required",
    IF(
        SBQQ__NetAmount__c <= 7500 && ISBLANK(CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c), 
        "Approval Required ",
        /* The rest of your formula here */
    )
)
```

Note that by virtue of only getting into the `else` part when SBQQ__NetAmount__c is *NOT* `> 7500`, it is guaranteed to be `<= 7500`.
So you don't need to check that condition explicitly

```java
IF(
    SBQQ__NetAmount__c > 7500, 
    "Approval Not Required",
    IF(
        /* No need to check if SBQQ__NetAmount__c <= 7500 here */
        ISBLANK(CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c), 
        "Approval Required ",
        /* The rest of your formula here */
    )
)
```

Also, you can save yourself quite a bit of typing here by using the `CASE()` function instead of nesting `IF()` functions for the `CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c` part.

`CASE()` starts by taking a parameter for the field you want to operate on
then you provide `<value>, <result>` pairs
and finally you end with the default result (if none of the values are matched)

```java
CASE(
    CPQ_Approval_Level_MAX__c,
    1, IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hl9z&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276904000', 'Green'),
    2, IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0158K0000000Xrs&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276872000', 'Blue'),
    3, IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hl9y&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276772000', 'Yellow'),
    4, IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hlA0&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652276863000', 'Red'),
    5, IMAGE('https://jmpsoftware--main2--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155b000006hl9x&oid=00D8K0000004cJ1&lastMod=1652290642000', 'Black'),
    "N/A"
)
```

Comment: Derek, the formula is valid but the issue is i do not think so it is possible to get flags/Approval required  or Flags/Not Approval required from that field .

Comment: @UlviaJ That's why I wrote the section about my assumptions of the behavior you were looking for. When asking questions here, it's important to include lots of details. The better you're able to convey what's in your mind, the more accurate the answers you'll get. I'm still going to leave my answer here because even if you do want text _and_ an image, the logic that underpins "why you need to write your formula _this_ particular way" and the advice about using `CASE()` is sound and could be helpful to other people who visit this question in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. I am a new user here still trying to used to it :)